# Electrical Engineering vs Computer Engineering?

Tags: digital-logic, microprocessor, computers, computer-architecture, education

I am trying to decide whether to major in EE or CE. To my knowledge, computer engineering has the same core focus as electrical engineering but with an emphasis on digital logic and microprocessors. Are there any major differences that I'm missing?

Comment: It depends a lot on the exact curriculum for your university.  Have you approached a counselor at your school with your question?

Comment: This question has no short or universally correct answer.

Comment: As the first answer says, this depends on your uni. CE can be very close to EE or much much closer to CS, it varies.

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends highly on the institution you attend. I am taking Computer Science with a digital systems emphasis, which means I take much of the same classes as CE students but not some of the more advanced signals or circuits classes. The differences between EE and CE are not standardized, some places even refuse to offer a CE degree preferring instead to consider the two degrees merely two different emphases in EE.

I think the real question here is what do you want to do with your career?  Do you want to get an advanced degree? Do you want to work with alot of analog components? Do you like programming? I could go on and on.

I think in the big picture if I were you I wouldn't worry about it too much, pick what's more interesting to you. Both degrees open up to you basically the same career paths, and especially if you go on to an advanced degree you will always be able to take classes on whatever you might have missed by not choosing the other degree. I've known of people who have gone on to get an advanced degree in Computer Science after an undergraduate degree in electrical, there is no reason why you couldn't do something similar once you've figured out more your interests.

I hope this helps.